# Maximal cyclic subgroups

Tags: group-theory, maximal-subgroup

Can we classify the groups for which every maximal cyclic subgroup is of same order and intersection of any two maximal cyclic subgroups is identity?

For example in case of abelian groups $$G=\mathbb{Z}_p\times \mathbb{Z}_p \times \cdots \times \mathbb{Z}_p$$

Can we do same kind of classification for non abelian groups?

Is there any example or some contradictions such that no such non abelian group exists which satisfy both these properties.
Any suggestion will be helpful.

Comment: Welcome Parveen. It's better to make the title short. Instead, you can ask in the body. This could ease others to find and to view the question. Thanks

Comment: Direct product of finite number of   groups is cylcic when greatest common divisor of their cradinalities is equal to 1. For maximal cyclic subgroup try to construct subgroups of maximum order such that greatest commom divisor of their cardinalities is 1

Comment: With non-abelian groups, thing get hairy pretty fast. Even if there are no cyclic subgroups with more than two elements (which automatically ensures your second condition), nothing good can be said.

Comment: @IvanNeretin If there are no cyclic subgroups with more than two elements, then every nonidentity element has order 2, so the group is abelian. So even this is not possible for nonabelian groups.

Comment: @ckefa Sorry, I was thinking of infinite groups. In the finite case, of course, what you said is right.

Comment: Any group of prime exponent $p$ has this property, and there are nonabelian examples for $p > 2$. I wonder whether there are any more examples.